# writing on global vector<int>

Tags: c++, vector

heres my code the problem is that when i attempt to write on a global vector through a function the prog throws exception

```
//global elements
vector <int> par; 
int t = 0;

void fun(int V)
{ 
    for(int i = 0; i < V ; ++i)
    par.at(i) = i ;
}

int main()
{
    int V;
    cin >> V;

    par.reserve(V);

    for(int i = 0 ; i < V ; ++i)
        par[i] = i;

    //following code fails to print anything??
    for(auto it : disc)     cout<<it<<' '<<"hello";

    //this throws exception

    fun(V);
}
```

Comment: Your vector is empty. You need to fill it with at least V elements. This has nothing to do with the vector being global.

Comment: actually i wrote disc in place of par there,sorry my bad..

Comment: Use `std::iota` instead of that `par[i] = i;` loop.

Comment: This is not such a bad question, I'm upvoting for balance.

Comment: You may argue it's not bad, but we've had more than one question caused by confusing reserve and resize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is that while [`std::vector::reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) reserves memory for expansion, it doesn't actually increase the size of the vector. That means that when you do e.g. `par[i] = i` you are indexing out of bounds of the vector, which leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You still have to use `push_back` to add elements.

---

There's another solution as well, and is assign to the global vector another vector of the correct size, and you can set the size in the [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector):

```
std::cin >> v;
par = std::vector<int>(v);
```

The above creates a temporary vector containing `v` entries, and copies that vector to `par`, before the temporary vector is destructed.